# .text() giving all text elements within element

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

The function below is suppose to give me an alert asking if I'm sure I want to delete the selected user. However, the alert is giving me a list of all users and not the selected one.

```
var user, group, strHTMLSiteUsers, strHTMLSiteGroups, strHTMLAvailable, strHTMLAssigned, arrOptionsAssigned, arrGroups, arrUsers, intOpts, booMatch, booErr;

$(document).ready(function(){ 
    user = $('#my_SiteUsers');
    group = $('#my_SiteGroups');
    groupsAssigned = $("#my_SPGroupsAssigned").html("Cats");
    groupAvailable = $("#my_SPGroupsAvailable").html("Cats");
    userAssigned = $("#my_SPUsersAssigned").html("Cats");
    userAvailable = $("#my_SPUsersAvailable").html("Cats");

    $("button").click(function() { return false; });

    populateUsers();
    populateGroups();
});

 if(user.val()!= null){
    var removeConfirm = confirm("You are about to delete "+user.text()+" from SharePoint. Are you sure?");
    if(removeConfirm){
      $().SPServices({
        operation:"RemoveUserFromWeb",
        userLoginName: user.val(),
        async:true,
        completefunc: function (xData,Status){
            alert(user.text()+ " deleted succesfully");
        }
      });
    }
  }else{
    alert("Please select a user");
  }
}
```

HTML:

```
 <select id="my_SiteUsers" style="width:200px;" onchange="RefreshGroupLists()">
        <option value='default' disabled="disabled">Select a user</option>
      </select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get only selected user

```
user.find('option:selected').text()
```

Answer (score 1):

Get the selected user text.

```
var user_text = $('#my_SiteUsers option:selected').text();


   var user_text = user.find("option:selected").text();
```

Comment: If I have user=$('#my_SiteUsers), is there any way I can get the selected option text from that without having to create a new variable? Creating more variables is what I'm trying to avoid.

Answer (score 1):

You may use

```
user.find(':selected').text();
```

In your code, it could be

```
alert(user.find(':selected').text() + " deleted succesfully");
```

[**DEMO.**](http://jsfiddle.net/5j9kh/)

Answer (score 1):

```
You can use if you are using select box:

var userText = $('#my_SiteUsers option:selected').text();
alert(userText);

var userText = $('#my_SiteUsers').find(':selected').text();
alert(userText);
```